# Input/Output error during write on /dev/sda, how do I solve this?

Tags: hard-drive, installation

I will try to make a long story short. My father recently quit his job and than gave me his Lenovo X1 Carbon gen 3 he got from his firm. The operating system pre- installed on it was Windows 7 with disk encryption from McAffe.

So when I got it I wanted to install Debian9. I did as I always do and just create a USB and go through the setup. When I reach the last step, removing current operating system and install the new one, I got an error that say

> Error!!!
>
> Input/Output error during write on /dev/sda

With options Retry, Ignore and Cancel. First time it occurred I canceled and tried booting up windows again. But it had been removed. Left is a text

> McAffe Drive Encryption
>
> Fatal Error: [0xEF000008] Failed to load cryptographic module

After reinstalling the USB device and trying again same thing happen. Ignoring the problem does not work eater.

After some digging I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZxrQQM7xDQ) video and [this](https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Encryption-ePO-Managed/Fatal-Error-0xEE000008-Failed-to-load-cryptographic-Module/m-p/352575#M5087) forum post addressing the problem. What the man in the video is saying I have no idea about, but the forum post is much clearer.

What I should do is to go to Storage Option and change from SATA to AHCI, but I can not for the life of me find Storage Option or any storage config on the BIOS.

What I really want to do is to just get rid of everything and have Linux on it, that's it. Have never experienced something like this. Can anyone maybe give me some tip on how I should move on with this problem? If I buy a new SSD, the McAffe crap should only be on this hard drive, right? So that is maybe a last resort, but it feels like a more cheaper way is possible. Diagnostics on the SSD say it is perfectly fine.

Have also tried to run DBAN in hope it will be wiped, only that it will take about 250h, figured I will maybe ask if it is worth the effort before doing it.

Edit: I do not know if the McAffe encryption have anything to do with the error of installing the OS, but it feels like it since Windows got removed as expected, but McAffe did not. Correct me if I am wrong

Edit 2: Sorry for a long follow up, but solved it by handing it over to lenovo support. Idnk how they removed it, but it was something with the BIOS that McAffe installed on there. Bying a new SSD Will Not Work! Do not spend money on a new drive because of this, it will not work. The problem is in the BIOS, not the drive

Comment: It's not change "SATA to AHCI". AHCI (recommended indeed) is just one of the SATA modes so you'll be changing from something else, the current setting, to AHCI. Find "Serial ATA" in the BIOS settings. Once changed to the proper mode try again to install Debian.

Comment: The McAfee error is irrelevant. You'll be cleaning that drive and that includes the McAfee encryption. If already in the AHCI mode and/or the same I/O error occurs it means that probably the drive has failed.

Comment: BTW; this problem was fixed by handing it over to lenovo support with a message to "remove McAffe froim every single aspect of the system". I think it was that McAffe had placed some crap on the BIOS startup to make it more "secure". But do not know. Would be nice to know how to remove it by myself